# Is Hilbert–Schmidt and Frobenius norm the same?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, terminology, norms

From the definition on $\Bbb R$ those two norm are the same:

- the [Frobenius norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNorm.html),
- the [Hilbert-Schmidt norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hilbert-SchmidtNorm.html).

Is there some difference (on $\Bbb C$) or historical reason for two names for the same thing?
If there is a historical reason I would actually like to hear about it.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) says the name Frobenius norm is typically used for finite-length vectors, while the name Hilbert-Schmidt norm typically refers to an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

Linear Operator vs Matrix

The [Hilbert-Schmidt norm](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hilbert-Schmidt_norm) is a norm on linear operators that relies on the domain and codomain of the linear operator being Hilbert spaces. That is, they must have inner products and thus vector-norms.

By contrast, the Frobenius norm is a norm on matrices.

The key point is that the matrix of a linear operator changes with basis, and thus a norm for a linear operator needs to be defined independent of basis. The HS norm does that while the Frobenius norm does not.

**Definition:** The Hilbert-Schmidt norm $\vert T \vert$ of a linear operator $T$ mapping from a Hilbert space $H$ to a Hilbert space $H_1$ is $\sum\limits_{e \in B} \Vert T e\Vert_{H_1}$ where $b$ is an orthonormal basis of $H$.

If the domain and codomain are the same, $H=H_1$ then this reduces to $\vert T \vert^2 = \sum\limits_{(e_1,e_2) \in B^2} \langle e_1, T e_2 \rangle_{H}$, which is the Frobeneous norm of the matrix of $T$ in the orthonormal basis $B$. If you stop there, you might go thinking that the HS norm and Frobenius norm are the same.

To see why they are different, consider the derivateive opperator $\frac{d}{dx}$ on the polynomial space $\text{Span}\{ 1, x, x^2 \}$ with inner product $\langle x^m,x^n\rangle = \delta_{m,n}$, the kronecker delta.

In the orthonormal basis $B_1=[1,x,x^2]$ the matrix of $\frac{d}{dx}$ is
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
0&1&0 \\
0&0&2\\
0&0&0
\end{array}
\right].
$$
Thus the Hilbert schmidt norm of this linear operator is $\sqrt{5}$, which is the Frobeneous norm of the operator in this basis $B_1$.

In the non-orthonormal basis $B_2=[1+x,x,x^2]$ the matrix of $\frac{d}{dx}$ is
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&0 \\
-1&-1 &2\\
0&0&0
\end{array}
\right].
$$
and the Frobeneous norm of that matrix is $\sqrt{8}$.